# Javascript Error in Ubuntu Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, referenceerror

I am working with jquery, javascript, php in Ubuntu Platform.  In the page i am sending an ajax request through jquery to php file and getting response text.  This program was running successfully in windows-(wamp) platform and online.
But in Ubuntu i am getting javascript error.  The code follows...

```
    url = "index.php";

    $.get(url,{
            'action': 'Loan',
        },
        function(responseText){     
            alert(responseText);
        },
        "html"
    );
```

In Ubuntu i am getting this error,
**"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"**.  This error was showing at $.get line.  In the script tag i included jquery library file too.  I dont know why this is error is coming.  Please solve my issue.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/emicalculator/
This is the page i am working on.  Once the Calculate image is clicked,  the values are calculated through jquery ajax request and the values are displayed below.  It is working fine on server.  In my lampp localhost i am getting the error defined above.

Comment: Please provide full code

Comment: I'm not experiencing this error.

Comment: I am checking with Chromium and firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419724/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ is not defined` on JQuery means the JQuery library is not loaded.

It can happen due to many reasons such as,

1. Path on Windows  is not same in Ubuntu.
2. In windows file names are case insensitive but in Linux its case sensitive.

I suggest you use JQuery from google.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" means that the JQuery library is not loaded.

You will find all CDN [here](http://code.jquery.com/) to include the version of JQuery that you need

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the dollar sign use jQuery.get if it still not working trying verifying your jquery if it exists or not(404). If it exists, open maybe its just an empty file.

Comment: $ is not defined means no other library has defined it, let alone jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the jquery.
The easiest way which works for me is inserting:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```