# Animated Text in JS not working at my place, but at Codepen example

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m trying to use a piece of html,css,javascript code in codepen.io site [This is the link to the sample i want to use](http://codepen.io/fmirabelli/pen/oxqpgj)

But when I put it on my code, I suppose that the javascript function is not working

This is the html code where I´m using it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sorteo USB Solutions</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<head>
<body onload="funtion()">
    <section class="full-screen">
        <div class="wheel-03">
            <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="wheel-svg" version="1.1"
                 width="800" height="400"
                 viewBox="0 0 800 400">
                <g transform="translate(0,0)">
                    <g transform="translate(0,250)" class="wheel-container">
                        <text x="0" y="-225" class="term term00">SMELL</text>
                        <text x="0" y="-150" class="term term01">HELL</text>
                        <text x="0" y="-75" class="term term02">SHOCK</text>
                        <text x="0" y="0" class="term term03">BRAND</text>
                        <text x="0" y="75" class="term term04">COOL</text>
                        <text x="0" y="150" class="term term05">NICE</text>
                        <text x="0" y="225" class="term term06">EYE</text>
                        <text x="0" y="300" class="term term07">SMELL</text>
                        <text x="0" y="375" class="term term08">HELL</text>
                        <text x="0" y="450" class="term term09">SHOCK</text>
                        <text x="0" y="525" class="term term10">BRAND</text>
                        <text x="0" y="600" class="term term11">COOL</text>
                        <text x="0" y="675" class="term term12">ROQUE SANTA  CRUZ</text>
                        <text x="0" y="750" class="term term13">EYE</text>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

The css stylesheet and the js script referred in the html code contains the same code as the sample in codepen.

I'm using byethost server to test it with apache 2.2.15 in a linux server kernel version 3.2.40

I´woud like to know in the sample why the text is not spinning as in the codepen site.

thank you

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. You left out the JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: please post your JS code here - the exact code you are using in your project

Comment: The problem should be pretty obvious if you look at the Console in your developer tools and read the error message there.

Comment: What is this: `<body onload="funtion()">` supposed to do?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998542/javascript-error-in-ubuntu-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined

Comment: thanks for your answers, i'm editing to upload the js and the css too

Comment: I was an html error, see CalvT answer for the solution, thank you all for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Codepen has two external scripts that you haven't included.

Also, you have placed your custom script in the `<head>` element but Codepen includes that at the end of the `<body>`, just after your `</section>`

So you would end up with:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Also, remove the `<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` out of your `<head>` element

Another thing - unrelated but your closing head tag is missing the `/` - it should be `</head>` not `<head>`.

So following my answer, here is your complete HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sorteo USB Solutions</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body onload="funtion()">
<section class="full-screen">
    <div class="wheel-03">
        <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="wheel-svg" version="1.1"
             width="800" height="400"
             viewBox="0 0 800 400">
            <g transform="translate(0,0)">
                <g transform="translate(0,250)" class="wheel-container">
                    <text x="0" y="-225" class="term term00">SMELL</text>
                    <text x="0" y="-150" class="term term01">HELL</text>
                    <text x="0" y="-75" class="term term02">SHOCK</text>
                    <text x="0" y="0" class="term term03">BRAND</text>
                    <text x="0" y="75" class="term term04">COOL</text>
                    <text x="0" y="150" class="term term05">NICE</text>
                    <text x="0" y="225" class="term term06">EYE</text>
                    <text x="0" y="300" class="term term07">SMELL</text>
                    <text x="0" y="375" class="term term08">HELL</text>
                    <text x="0" y="450" class="term term09">SHOCK</text>
                    <text x="0" y="525" class="term term10">BRAND</text>
                    <text x="0" y="600" class="term term11">COOL</text>
                    <text x="0" y="675" class="term term12">ROQUE SANTA  CRUZ</text>
                    <text x="0" y="750" class="term term13">EYE</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @FerMirabelli glad I could help :)