# value attribute is showing null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of ID but its showing null
link  https://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/zwjrXZ

```
function printCurrentTab(){
var content = "";
var activeTab = document.getElementById('activeDisTab').value;
```

getting error here in var activeTab

Comment: You get an error because you use jquery `content += $('#' + activeTab).html();` but did not include it. `document.getElementById('activeDisTab')` on its own works just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419724/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

Juste replace jQuery part with plain JavaScript

Instead of this `content += $('#' + activeTab).html();`
Use this `content += document.getElementById('activeDisTab').value;`

Comment: now I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it is `value` not `innerHTML`, I have edited my answer